# EditorWindow.GetWindow doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code:

```
public class CrazyWindow: EditorWindow 
{
    [MenuItem("Window/CrazyWindow")]
    public static void Window()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(CrazyWindow));

        Debug.Log("It should have appeared!");
    }

    string test = "";
    public void OnGUI()
    {
        test = EditorGUILayout.TextField ("Text Field", test );
    }
}
```

I'm using Unity3D v. 4.3.4f1 (free version) on Windows 7.
I have no idea why this is happening, as I can see in tutorials in the internet, that's how it should be done. The script is also in the Editor folder.

I'm able to click on the option "CrazyWindow" in the window menu, and I also get the Debug message informing me that the window should be working, but nothing happens besides that. No window is created at all!

What might be the cause of my problem?

Comment: What often helps in such a case is switching layouts. The resets window states and subsequently your code should work. This happens on occasion for our editor code as well.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

As Bart mentioned, I was using a custom Editor Layout, which was the case for the window not showing.

I just switched to one of the factory editor layouts and: ta dah, the window was there...

Pretty buggy thought.

Comment: Glad that solved it. I'll consider reporting this as a bug. It had us puzzled for a while as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the 'CrazyWindow' part in the MenuItem and of the class itself. Unity remembers whether a window is visible or not and somehow something goes wrong there. Probably it thinks your window is visible (in cache) while actually it is not.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going crazy. Every window I'd moved to a new MenuItem location would no longer open. Reverting to the factory layout fixed it for me.

Unity is so ridiculously buggy, it's maddening.

Answer (score 0):

As Bart said, it remembers useless things
Just make it remember what we want it to

```
private void OnLostFocus() {
    GetWindow<CrazyWindow>().Close();
}
```